window.showDirectoryPicker() not allowed error file picker already active
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const pre = document.getElementById('pre');

btn.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {

  try {
      const dirHandle = await window.showDirectoryPicker();
      pre.innerHTML = `${dirHandle.name}`;
  } 
  catch (error) {       
      console.log(error);      
  }

});

When I click "Open" without selecting any directory and close the window, and after this , when I click the button again (btn), it gives "file already active" every time and does not open the directory window. Any solutions?

try   btn.disabled = true; before try and finally { btn.disabled = false; } after catch. Try this way. This is happening because you are not handling it properly.

i tried the error is gone but still same not opening now

Can you track the state of the dialog window?

Im using Electron and getting this on console-> NotAllowedError: Failed to execute 'showDirectoryPicker' on 'Window': File picker already active.

@pinug did you ever find a solution to this?

@twhitney nope : /

@pinug , I actually found out a solution after looking through issues in the electron github repo.  It is an electron-specific issue that they've added a workaround for.  Hopefully it will help your use-case, if this is something you're still working on:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/79270236/5964556

I highly recommend installing Electron Fiddle and making a tiny directory-picker POC.  showDirectoryPicker() behaves markedly different between versions because the Electron devs iteratively replaced the native Browser implementation with their own implementation over the course of multiple Electron versions, as far as I can tell.
